# Reserving a core for system processes to prevent wedging

Tags: multi-core

I am working on a multi-core machine (running Ubuntu 14.04 server), where some programs seem to use up all resources causing wedging. Is there a way I can reserve one core for the os processes to prevent such a scenario?

Comment: Did you tried the `nice` option when running processes ? It could be a solution.

Comment: No. I'll look into it.